# How to run gtests without logging from google log?

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm running unit tests with gtest. However I'm also using google glog in the code I'm testing. Unfortunately this output gets in the way of the test results and looks messy. How do I do I get rid of the glog output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you mind editing your question to complete it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work, suppressing all log messages.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  FLAGS_logtostderr = true;
  FLAGS_minloglevel = 5;
  google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);
  // Start running unit tests here
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend doing something like this:

Answer (score 1):

From the Advanced Guide, define your own empty EventListener and surpass all debug log and then remove the default printer from the event listener.

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

        // Gets hold of the event listener list.
        ::testing::TestEventListeners& listeners =
        ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners();

        // Removes the default console output listener from the list so it will
        // not receive events from Google Test and won't print any output. Since
        // this operation transfers ownership of the listener to the caller we
        // have to delete it as well.
        delete listeners.Release(listeners.default_result_printer());

       // Adds a listener to the end.  Google Test takes the ownership.
       // Basically you can define an empty class MinimalistPrinter
       // derived from EmptyTestEventListener
       listeners.Append(new MinimalistPrinter);
       return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
  }
```

Sample program [here](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/samples/sample9_unittest.cc)

Comment: This gets rid of the _test_ output. The question is about getting rid of the _log_ output.